# How to get object ID for custom file upload path?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm trying to get a path to save a file like `<employee_id>/<prefix>_<filename>`. How do I get the `<employee_id>` in the `User_directory_path` class?

In this code I can only get `<license_id>`:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django_minio_backend import MinioBackend

@deconstructible
class User_directory_path(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        return f'{instance.id}/{self.prefix}_{filename}'


class DocumentStatus(models.TextChoices):
    NOT_UPLOADED = 'NOT_UPLOADED'
    ON_REVIEW = 'ON_REVIEW'


class License(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
    license_0 = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='License(1)',
        storage=MinioBackend(
            bucket_name='django-backend-private',
            replace_existing=True),
        upload_to=User_directory_path('license_0'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    license_0_status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='License(1) Status',
        max_length=15,
        choices=DocumentStatus.choices,
        default=DocumentStatus.NOT_UPLOADED)
    license_1 = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='License(2)',
        storage=MinioBackend(
            bucket_name='django-backend-private',
            replace_existing=True),
        upload_to=User_directory_path('license_1'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    license_1_status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='License(2) Status',
        max_length=15,
        choices=DocumentStatus.choices,
        default=DocumentStatus.NOT_UPLOADED)


class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
    licenses = models.ManyToManyField(License, blank=True)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It makes no sense to have an `employee_id`: you use a `ManyToManyField`, so there can be zero, one or more `Employee`s, and even if there is exactly 9one, the two are *linked* only *after* construction of the `License` and `Employee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to have an `employee_id`: you use a `ManyToManyField`, so there can be zero, one or more `Employee`s, and even if there is exactly 9one, the two are *linked* only *after* construction of the `License` and `Employee`.

The modeling thus looks wrong, likely you intended to work with:

```
class License(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
    license_0 = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='License(1)',
        storage=MinioBackend(
            bucket_name='django-backend-private', replace_existing=True
        ),
        upload_to=UserDirectoryPath('license_0'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    license_0_status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='License(1) Status',
        max_length=15,
        choices=DocumentStatus.choices,
        default=DocumentStatus.NOT_UPLOADED,
    )
    license_1 = models.FileField(
        verbose_name='License(2)',
        storage=MinioBackend(
            bucket_name='django-backend-private', replace_existing=True
        ),
        upload_to=User_directory_path('license_1'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    license_1_status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='License(2) Status',
        max_length=15,
        choices=DocumentStatus.choices,
        default=DocumentStatus.NOT_UPLOADED,
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

in which case, you use:

```
@deconstructible
class UserDirectoryPath(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        return f'{instance.employee_id}/{self.prefix}_{filename}'
```

---

> **Note**: Please use an [**`UUIDField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) instead of a [**`CharField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#charfield) to store a UUID, this can do validation to check if the entered data is indeed a UUID.